# `stat_function` of ggplot doesn't work with a function with vector multiplication

Tags: r, windows, ggplot2, anonymous-function, matrix-multiplication

## Environtment

- Windows 8.1 64bit
- R 3.4.3

## Issue

I am trying to get ggplot to plot a function with data.

```
dat <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=(1:10)^3) # sample data
param <- c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3) # sample parameters
ggplot(dat, aes(x,y)) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_function(fun=function(x) 1/(c(1, log(x), (log(x))^3) %*% param))
```

But this gives me the following error.

> Warning message:
>   Computation failed in `stat_function()`:
>   non-conformable arguments

I searched the Internet with "Computation failed in `stat_function()`" but couldn't find much information.

So I tried to figure out what's going on. In the end, it seemed to me a function with vector multiplication is causing the error.

Here are the reasons.

It works without vector multiplication.

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x,y)) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_function(fun=function(x) log(x)*200)
```

It also works with vector multiplication and without `x`.

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x,y)) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_function(fun=function(x) c(100,200,300) %*% param)
```

But it doesn't work with both of them.

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x,y)) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_function(fun=function(x) c(log(x)*100,200,300) %*% param)
```

An obvious workaround is to manually calculate the output of the function for x with an interval small enough to make the plot smooth. The following worked.

```
xfun = seq(1,10,0.1)
yfun = sapply(xfun, function(x) 1/(c(1, log(x), (log(x))^3) %*% param))
datfun = data.frame(x=xfun, y=yfun)
ggplot(dat, aes(x,y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(data=datfun)
```

But I still don't have any idea what the root of the error is. Is this a known bug? Or am I getting wrong somewhere? Is there a way to fix this?

## EDIT 2018-3-25 12:09 GMT

At first I said "matrix multiplication" but it was a mistake. It should have been "vector multiplication." Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: did you try: `ggplot(dat, aes(x,y)) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_function(fun = function(x) sapply(x, function(z) 1/(c(1, log(z), (log(z))^3) %*% param)))`?

Comment: do you want `cbind` instead of `c` - as `c` just concatenates in to one long vector (hence non-conformable with matrix multi)

Comment: @missuse it worked. I got it. What's passed to `stat_function` is not a numeric but **a vector of values**.

Comment: also check @user20650 comment, its much more elegant.